# Temperature rise during friction

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, temperature, friction, dissipation

Why does the temperature increase when the load increases during friction?
Why does the temperature increase when the contact time increases during friction?

Comment: What is "contract time?"

Comment: I mean in contact time the time takes to stay under friction and two material in contact befor they stop or separated

Answer (score 2):

Conservation of energy.  It takes work to overcome friction and that work has to go some where.  The work goes to heat.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Friction diagram.]

Friction is caused when a Normal force ($L$ in the diagram above) pushes one surface onto another, causing a friction force of magnitude $F_f=\mu L$, with $\mu$ the coefficient of friction.

When a force $F > F_f$ drags the surface (of the bloc in the diagram) over the other surface (of the 'floor' in the diagram) work is being done:

$W = \int F_f ds = \int \mu L ds = \mu \int Lds$. In the simplest case where $L$ is constant, $W=\mu L \Delta s$.

This work is converted to heat energy (Enthalpy) completely.

So the higher the load $L$, the more heat is being released. More heat means higher temperature.

Similarly, maintaining the friction for a longer path $s$, that is for a longer time, also generates more heat.